# Linq Update excel sheet from Any

Tags: c#, excel, vba, linq

I'd like to update an Excel cell with the Total Hours value from a where clause. I know the way I am currently doing this is horribly inefficient. How can I change my Linq statement to be more performant?

```
if (employeeHours.Any(x => x.EmployeeName == newHours.EmployeeName && x.ChargeNumber == newHours.ChargeNumber))
{
    sheet.Cells[row, 5] = employeeHours.Where(x => x.EmployeeName == newHours.EmployeeName && x.ChargeNumber == newHours.ChargeNumber).FirstOrDefault().TotalHours;
}
```

Comment: This question looks like a Code Review code to me rather than a SO question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is a bit redundant. Also, is employee name or charge number unique? If so, a .Single() statement would be more appropriate. If they aren't unique, I'd just do the following:

```
var hours = employeeHours.Where(x => x.EmployeeName == newHours.EmployeeName && x.ChargeNumber == newHours.ChargeNumber)?.FirstOrDefault()?.TotalHours;

if (hours != null)
    sheet.Cells[row, 5] = hours;
```

Note the use of the null conditional operator ?. before and after the FirstOrDefault() method. This will essentially prevent a null exception error from being thrown if there's no entry that matches your condition, or if the entry's TotalHours property is null. You could also use First() and wrap it in a try catch block, since First() throws an error if there's no entry found (FirstOrDefault() will set the value equal to null if there's no entry found). Here's the try/catch approach:

```
try
{
    sheet.Cells[row, 5] = employeeHours.Where(x => x.EmployeeName == newHours.EmployeeName && x.ChargeNumber == newHours.ChargeNumber).First().TotalHours;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // handle errors here
    throw;
}
```

**Update:** Since both the EmployeeName and ChargeNumber make a unique Id when used with one another, I'd update your code to the following:

```
var hours = employeeHours.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeName == newHours.EmployeeName && x.ChargeNumber == newHours.ChargeNumber)?.TotalHours;

if (hours != null)
    sheet.Cells[row, 5] = hours;
```

Comment: Together the Employee and Charge Number make a unique key.

Comment: @LarryBargers If that's the case, take a look at the update in my original post.